# Problems with WordPress with Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics-api

I recently tried to add Google Analytics to our WordPress Blog, and now I get 404 errors. I'm able to log in through the wp_admin and am copying all of the entries we have in order to delete the blog and start fresh, but I would like to know if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you used a plugin or hardcoded into your theme?

If it was installed by plugin, deactivate it and add this into your functions.php

```
add_action('wp_header', 'add_googleanalytics');

function add_googleanalytics() { ?>

// Google Analytics code

<?php }
```

Comment: What function should that go in?

Comment: Your google analytics code. [Check this guide as reference](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-install-google-analytics-in-wordpress/)

Comment: There are a huge variety of functions in functions.php- mysql2date, current_time, date_i18n, etc. Do I need to put it in it's own function? How do I name the function?

Comment: @TomJeffries add the code (with the JavaScript code  from your google analytics profile) at the bottom of your function.php file (before the '?>' tag)

Comment: So that means it goes in the function "function wp_post_preview_js()"?

Comment: No, function add_googleanalytics() is a function by itself, you need to put outside other functions, directly into your functions.php of your wordpress theme.

Comment: Yesterday I kept getting an error when I put "add_action('wp_header', 'add_googleanalytics');" outside of functions. Where does that go

Comment: @TomJeffries Can you share a gist or a pastebin of your functions.php?

Comment: Never mind, I deleted the blog and am starting again.